# Неккоректно работает кнопка рестарта игры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Cделал кнопку перезагрузки в игре, но после неё могу только в меню выйти `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` и по новой начать игру, что с этим делать?

Вот скрипт кнопки рестарт

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Restart : MonoBehaviour
{
public void OnClick()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScreen");
}
}
```

вот часть основы,которая ругается

```
    GameObject persistantObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PersistantObj") as GameObject;
    gameMode = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistanceScript>().gameMode;
    Destroy(persistantObj);
```

и сам persistant

```
public string gameMode;

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оператор as](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) работает таким образом, что если к типу справа от него привести объект не удается, то он записывает в переменную значение `null`. Отсюда и `NullReferenceException`

Соответственно при первой загрузке сцены у объект не удаляется благодаря

```
private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
}
```

Но при попытке перезагрузить вы его удаляете с помощью `Destroy` и не создаете заново при загрузке этой же сцены в последующие разы.

```
GameObject persistantObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PersistantObj") as GameObject;
    gameMode = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistanceScript>().gameMode;
    Destroy(persistantObj);
```

Решений несколько:

1. Не удалять объект при перезагрузке, а просто обновлять его [состояние](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.6.php) на то, которое должно быть на момент старта уровня.
2. Удалять объект и пересоздавать его вновь из [префаба](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Comment: Если не сложно,объясните,пожалуйста, как обновить его состояние (я тут совсем что-то новичок)

Comment: @WaferNait это уже другой вопрос)) Я там ссылочки оставил

Comment: @WaferNait если ответ помог, то отметьте его галочкой